# The "create wiki posts" privilege should be renamed to "create wiki answers"

Tags: feature-request, privileges, community-wiki, help-center

The 10-rep ["create wiki posts"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) privilege only applies to creating wiki *answers* nowadays. As of the changes to our CW system in 2014 ([Putting the Community back in Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/152515)), the only way a question can become community wiki is if a diamond moderator makes it so, so this privilege has nothing to do with CW questions anymore.

To reflect the current circumstances, this privilege should be renamed to "create wiki answers" and its page should be edited to reflect that change.

Comment: @Shadow shouldn't this be a [tag:bug-report]? They changed the code and forgot to update the documentation to match, which seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @muru well technically this might be correct, but still feels more like a feature request. You can add the [tag:bug] tag as well, and in (the unlikely) case a developer will actually do that change, they can remove one of those as they see fit.

Comment: I think calling it a feature request is correct. The current behaviour isn't wrong or broken per se, this just proposes to improve it.